# How do I make a Timer and increment a variable for every second that goes by

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# And I'm trying to make a little clicker game. I want to make it so that every second the variable PP is incremented if cslave is more than 0. I've tried a few different things that I saw in other code but I just can't make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clicker_Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer gameLoop = new Timer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gameLoop.Interval = 1000;
            gameLoop.Tick += Update;
            button2.Text = "Click here to buy Cookieze slave Cost 10 PP";
        }
        // Makes it so everytime you click the button it will add 1 to PP
        private double pp = 0;
        private int cslave = 0;
        private double cSlaveC = 10;

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pp++;
            string current = "Your current PP is ";
            label1.Text = current + pp.ToString();
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pp >= cSlaveC)
            {
                gameLoop.Start();
                pp -= cSlaveC;
                string current = "Your current PP is ";
                label1.Text = current + pp.ToString();
                cslave++;
                cSlaveC = cSlaveC * 2;
                string cslaveM = "You currently have ";
                string cslaveW = " Cookieze slaves";
                label2.Text = cslaveM + cslave + cslaveW;
                button2.Text = "Click here to buy Cookieze slave Cost " + cSlaveC + " PP";

            }

        }
        private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gameLoop.Start();
            pp++;
        }

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += (s,e) => 
{
    if(cslave > 0)
         pp++; 
 };
timer.Start();
```

Or using your code.

```
   var timer = new Timer();
   timer.Interval = 1000;
   timer.Tick += Update;
```

In your Button Click event

```
timer.Start();
```

And Finally in your Update Method

```
 if(cslave > 0)
             pp++;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code it didn't bring up any errors except asking me to change the "enclosing local scope" But I think I fixed that by just changing the letter to something, not in use. But this didn't do what I wanted I put it under my Button2 method and update but both didn't work is there somewhere specific I should put this and do I have to change anything to work for me.

Comment: if you need to start the timer only on the Button Click, then you can move the "timer.Start()" to the Button2_Click event.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect parts of your code

Comment: Oh silly me it did work I just need to keep updating my label to actually see the change in real time! Thank you for the help!